# Execute a javascript function on completion of C# async function

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, async-await

I have a jquery Ajax function

```
  var arr = {
                id: 1,
                run: true
            }
  $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Getdata", "Details")',
            data: { Batch: arr},
            type: "POST",
            success: function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    GenNamespace.Completed(result);
                }
            },
            error: function (result) { alert("Problem Occured"); },
        });
```

which calls c# async function, and on successful completion of the task i am executing some function  in jquery ajax success

```
       public async Task<JsonResult> GetData(Batch arr)
    {
        try
        {
            var success = false;
            var t = await Task.Run(() =>
            {
            //i am Performing long running task here
             return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            }
            });
            return t;
          }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

however this is a async function, so the value(success = false) gets returned to the jquery success even though the function is not completely executed, so how do i call the javascript function only upon completion of this task, is there a task completed notification or something which i could use here in this scenario?

Comment: Async controller actions are only asynchronous from the point of view of the asp.net thread, they are not asynchronous to the JavaScript client caller.

Comment: @BenRobinson- Yes, that's true, i wanted to know how i could use it for the advantage in this situation,

Comment: might be a silly question, but do you set success variable to true in Task.Run?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, the javscript will not see a difference between and async controller action and a normal one, the reason it returns success false seems to be because you are never setting it to true.

Comment: @ieaglle- Yes, i do set in the last line of the function, but initially it would be false, but it would not wait till the function gets completed, it would start the task and return to success of jqAjax.

Comment: @BenRobinson- Yes, absolutely right, javascript will not see diff between async and normal one, but i just wanted to know how to handle in this situation, on success i wanted to show some buttons which would be hidden initially. so i was checking for solution

Comment: well, anyway I would recommend using ASP.NET Web Api for such requests.

Comment: @G--, I've recreated your sample and everything is working for me, strange!

Comment: `the value gets returned to the jquery success even though the function is not completely executed` - no, that's completely wrong. Please post a minimal, reproducible example of the problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The next code works just as expected (and it is almost equal to yours):

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetData()
    {
        var succ = false;
        var taskRes = await Task.Run(async () =>
       {
           await Task.Delay(10000);
           succ = true;
           return Json(succ, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
       });

        return taskRes;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetData", "Home")',
        type: "POST",
        success: function (result) {
            console.log(result);
        },
        error: function (result) { alert("Problem Occured"); },
    });
```

After execution (10s) there's 'true' in console.

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this. I think what is happening for you is that you are calling the async task but the program will continue on and return. Untested...

UPDATE: This blocks and so removes any async benefits.

```
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetData(Batch arr)
    {
        try
        {
            return DoTask().Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        return null;
    }

    private async Task<JsonResult> DoTask()
    {
        var success = false;
        var t = await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            //i am Performing long running task here
            success = true;
            return Json(success, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        });
        return t;
    }
```

If you you wanted true async between the javascript client and your API I suggest you look at [SignalR](http://www.asp.net/signalr).

Comment: @deebo- thanks for the solution, i would check this and let you know.

Comment: [Result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd321468%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property blocks current thread so there is no point in async here.

Comment: @ieaglle- then i have completely misunderstood the concept, i would then have to read async again!

Comment: Yes sorry I should have been explicit about that in my answer. That is why I mentioned SignalR.

Comment: @deebo, SignalR allows duplex communication and it is not required here as I understood.

Comment: @ieaglle  may be off here but since the js is making an HTTP request, it must wait for the HTTP response. So the action method has to wait for the result of the long running task (unless you just return success based on the task being called no matter the success). The other option is send the request and return (maybe with a unique task identifier). Then the client will be notified via SignalR hub connection when long running task has completed. Am I off on something?

Answer (score 0):

You are not considering the stateless HTTP connection separating the client from the server. If the websocket was kept open, we could do all sorts async behavior like lazy loading of data between the client and server (Without EF). But with IObservable and Promises, there are other ways to accomplish true end-to-end async behavior.  IT all comes down to how you slice and dice.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).